# Why OpenCV Using BGR Colour Space Instead of RGB

Tags: opencv

Why `OpenCV` using `BGR` colour space instead of `RGB`. We all know that `RGB` is the convenient colour model for most of the computer graphics and also the human visual system works in a way that is similar to a `RGB` colour space. Is there any reason behind `OpenCV` `BGR` colour space?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BGR Color Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367449/bgr-color-space)

Comment: [here](http://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/) you can find an information about the question

Comment: @KateGregory, it not a dup. That question is a *what*. This question is a *why*.

Comment: The human visual system does not work like RGB at all.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As Satya Mallick, CEO, OpenCV, [blogged in 2015](https://learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/):

> "The reason why the early developers at OpenCV chose BGR color format is probably that back then BGR color format was popular among camera manufacturers and software providers. E.g. in Windows, when specifying color value using COLORREF they use the BGR format `0x00bbggrr`."
>
> "BGR was a choice made for historical reasons and now we have to live
> with it. In other words, BGR is the horse’s ass in OpenCV."

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304126/is-it-correct-to-answer-copying-from-comments-by-other-users

Comment: That doesn't explain why BGR was (then) popular in the first place.

Comment: Windows has only ever worked on little-endian machines. 0x00bbggrr is stored as R, G, B in memory. It seems to me that OpenCV’s choice was based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: It is quoted from https://learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format. State your sources

Comment: i think BGR was popular because the characters follow alphabet order.

Comment: The opposite question is why is RGB popular.

Comment: I wish they just rolled that back. "now we have to live with it" is how most of us feel when using it.

Comment: @eugenhu It is the order on the color spectrum

Comment: @SimonChemnitz-Thomsen If you sort by wavelength, it's BGR. If you sort by frequency, it's RGB. On google images you see both red-to-blue and blue-to-red if you search for color spectrum.

Answer (score 14):

OpenCV reads in images in BGR format (instead of RGB) because when OpenCV was first being developed, BGR color format was popular among camera manufacturers and image software providers. The red channel was considered one of the least important color channels, so was listed last, and many bitmaps use BGR format for image storage. However, now the standard has changed and most image software and cameras use RGB format, which is why, in programs, it's good practice to initially convert BGR images to RGB before analyzing or manipulating any images.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? As far as I know, it has always been RGB.

Answer (score 6):

Why? For historical reasons. In 1987, Microsoft Windows ran on the IBM PS/2, and an early IBM [video display controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_display_controller), [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array), made use of the [INMOS 171/176 RAMDAC chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAMDAC), which was easier to use when images were stored in BGR format.

See details at
[Why BGR color order - Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3025)

Comment: This still doesn’t explain why OpenCV stores blue in the first byte. The linked Q&A specifically talks about storing x0bgr such that red is the first byte read. On a little endian machine, x0bgr has red in the first byte, OpenCV stores blue in the first byte.