# Why the result of DIGITS and OpenCV 3.1 is different?

Tags: opencv, classification, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I use DIGIT to classify (I test GoogLeNet with Adaptive Gradient, Stochastic gradient descent, and Nesterov's accelerated gradient). The images are color and 256*256. After training I use "Test a single image" option and test one image. The result is show prefect match and classify image correctly. Then I use downloaded model for applying in OpenCV 3.1 (windows 64bit, visual studio 2013, Nvidia GPU) based on "http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html". However, always I got different class and wrong answer.
Edit:
I try `cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_BGR2RGB)` and the problem not solve. Still I got wrong result.
I try different `data transformations` like `none`, `image`, and `pixel`. Also different `solver type`.

Comment: Can you reproduce the numbers with the 'buran' image and the mentioned model from the tutorial?

Comment: Best Class: 'Google' , Probability: 66.8766%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be surprised if OpenCV 3 vs 2 is causing this issue. Instead, I expect that the discrepancy is due to a difference in data pre-processing.

Here's an example of how to do data pre-processing for a Caffe model that was trained in DIGITS:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/v4.0.0/examples/classification/example.py#L40-L85

Also make sure you read these "gotchas": https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/v4.0.0/examples/classification/README.md#limitations

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV uses by default the now very uncommon BGR (blue, green, red) ordering of the color channels. Normal is RGB.

[Why OpenCV Using BGR Colour Space Instead of RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556545/why-opencv-using-bgr-colour-space-instead-of-rgb)

This could explain the bad performance of the model.

Comment: Thank you but I try cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_BGR2RGB); and the problem not solve. Still I got wrong result.