# Why does this python program convert blue color to yellow when working on the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

The thing is, I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot
img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\Niranjan\Desktop\FINAL YEAR PROJECT\Python Codes\obj.jpg')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape
pts1 = np.float32([[170,220],[466,221],[110,540],[528,541]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[530,0],[0,542],[530,542]])
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(530,542))
pyplot.subplot(121),pyplot.imshow(img),pyplot.title('Input')
pyplot.subplot(122),pyplot.imshow(dst),pyplot.title('Output')
pyplot.show()
```

[image: the original image]

[image: The result of the python code]

So blue is getting converted to yellow... is this a hint that RGB is converted to CMYK?

what should i do to keep my colors same as original?

*note: This is not an ad

Comment: I think it is because you are reading the file as RGB but pyplot is treating it as BGR

Comment: but then whats the solution to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `img = img[:,:,::-1]` to shuffle the color channels form BGR to RGB.

```
pyplot.subplot(121),pyplot.imshow(img[:,:,::-1] ),pyplot.title('Input')
pyplot.subplot(122),pyplot.imshow(dst[:,:,::-1] ),pyplot.title('Output')
pyplot.show()
```

Here is the `matplotlib` input and output images.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @NiranjanDixit could you give me a vote up if my answer helps?

Answer (score 3):

[For historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556545/why-opencv-using-bgr-colour-space-instead-of-rgb), OpenCV uses a BGR color representation. You can convert your images before displaying them using:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: i tried this but it gives me "Assertion Failed open cv error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor