# TensorFlow video frames versus still images

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, png, video-processing

I am having a strange issue with TensorFlow that I suspect has a simple solution.

I am working with video data. To create my training data, I used `ffmpeg` to extract video frames to PNG files and then used LabelImg to create a bounding box dataset. The trained network works beautifully on these PNG files.

However, if I open a video using OpenCV and feed frames from the video to the network, it doesn't work at all. I use the OpenCV VideoCapture class like:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)
status, frame = video.read()
output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(frame, detection_graph)
```

Note that `run_inference_for_single_image` is a function provided by the TensorFlow library, the same used to run detection on a PNG file opened and transformed into a numpy array.

I get a few detections, but accuracy is reduced almost to zero. If instead I save the same frame as a PNG file and feed that file into the network, it works as expected.

What do I need to change to avoid the step of saving video frames as PNG files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV has this weird behavior of loading color images [in the BGR format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14556545/1735003). You can use

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

to convert them into RGB before feeding them to your net.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Call should be cv2.cvtColor (capital 'C').