# Opencv Circle Color

Tags: python, opencv

This code below will draw a red circle at x,y coordinates

```
>>cv2.circle(frame,(x, y), 10, (0,0,255), -1)
```

But the right rbg code for red color should be (255,0,0). When I printed out the color name, it showed blue.

```
>>print webcolors.rgb_to_name((0,0,255))
>>blue
```

Comment: Your image may be in BGR mode instead of RGB mode (which is why the components are backwards).

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV uses BGR color space for representing colors. So, your color code : `(0, 0, 255)` will be considered as `RED` in the `BGR` color space by OpenCV.

If you want to draw blue circle you have to pass color code as `(255, 0, 0)`

For more details about the color space in OpenCV go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556545/why-opencv-using-bgr-colour-space-instead-of-rgb)