# what does [:, :, ::-1] mean in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am running a program and I have the code below. But I do not know what does that `[:, :, ::-1]` do exactly. I get the following error when I run the program so understanding the function of `[:, :, ::-1]` will help me to debug. Thanks.

```
while True:
    ix = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(lists)), batch_size)
    imgs = []
    labels = []
    for i in ix:
        # images
        img_path = img_dir + lists.iloc[i, 0] + '.png'
        original_img = cv2.imread(img_path)[:, :, ::-1]
        resized_img = cv2.resize(original_img, dims+[3])
        array_img = img_to_array(resized_img)/255
        imgs.append(array_img)
```

error:

```
original_img = cv2.imread(img_path)[:, :, ::-1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It's wacky but legal syntax: an object subscripted by a tuple of slices. I guess that's how cv2 does things? But the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error just means that the `imread` function returned `None`. I don't know why it would do that instead of raising an exception, but I imagine it means there was some problem reading the image file?

Comment: cv2 images are numpy ndarrays, so this slice syntax is not specific to cv2.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is numpy-specific and will not work for most python objects. The `:` means "take everything in this dimension" and the `::-1` means "take everything in this dimension but backwards." Your matrix has three dimensions: height, width and color. Here you're flipping the color from BGR to RGB. This is necessary because OpenCV has colors in BGR (blue/green/red) order, while most other imaging libraries have them in RGB order. This code will switch the image from OpenCV format to whatever format you'll display it in.

Answer (score 8):

Let's say your image has three planes - R, G and B. Then the command `[:, :, ::-1]` will reverse the order of the color planes, making them B, G and R. This is done because by convention, OpenCV used BGR format (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33787594/1586200)). So you are converting BGR to RGB simply because we like RGB nowadays.

However, your error has nothing do with the understanding of the command. The problem is that the `cv2.imread()` command cannot read the image and it is returning `None`. It is possible that you have given the wrong path.