# Byte order for packed images

Tags: c++, c, rgb

So from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space, I learned that the byte order for ARGB is, from lowest address to highest address, BGRA, on a little endian machine in certain interpretations.

How does this effect the naming convention of packed data eg a `uint8_t ar[]={R,G,B,R,G,B,R,G,B}`?

Comment: Which naming convention?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy The one listed in the RGBA article in wikipedia, the endianess based naming convention (not the byte-order based naming convention).

Comment: It's not a naming convention, it's a byte order. The naming convention is that B=blue, R=red, etc. –  EJP 3 hours ago

Comment: @EJP That is exactly wrong, actually. ARGB is a VALUE naming convention (while the byte order will be reverse, the integer value of the pixel will (theoretically) be the same on different machines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little endian by definition stores the bytes of a number in reverse order. This is not strictly necessary if you are treating them as byte arrays however any vaguely efficient code base will actually treat the 4 bytes as a 32 bit unsigned integer. This will speed up software blitting by a factor of almost 4.

Now the real question is why. This comes from the fact that when treating a pixel as a 32 bit int as described above coders want to be able to run arithmetic and shifts in a predictable way. This relies on the bytes being in reverse order.

In short, this is not actually odd as in little endian machines the last byte (highest address) is actually the most significant byte and the first the least significant. Thus a field like this will naturally be in reverse order so it is the correct way around when treated as a number (as a number it will appear ARGB but as a byte array it will appear BGRA).

Sorry if this is unclear, but I hope it helps. If you do not understand or I have missed something please comment.

Comment: I understand that. What I don't understand is how this maps to packed data types: it would appear it can't?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Well it appears the main difference is that the packed version is simply missing the alpha channel. You should be able to convert between the two fairly easily with a few bitwise shifts and memcopies.

Comment: I know how to convert it. The ARGB "naming convention" is by pixel value, not byte order. But the same naming convention doesn't make sense with packed data types. [RGBR] and [BGRB] are very different values when comparing byte space. The convention could still hold if you define the pixel value as (value>>8), but this seems...well weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing data in a byte array like you have specified, you are using BGR format which is basically RGB reversed:

[bgr-color-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367449/bgr-color-space)