# How to convert a hexidecimal value to Int(16) Little Endian in Javascript

Tags: javascript, endianness

For example, if I have an RGB value of 66, 135, 245 which translates to #4287f5, how would I get the int(16) Little Endian value?

Comment: Are you sure you want int(16)? Each of R, G and B values are unsigned int(8) from 0 to 255, total: 24 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows bit-shifts, but be careful with operator precedence.
The parentheses are necessary here.

```
function colorInteger(r,g,b){
    return (r<<16) + (g<<8) + b
}
```

Now `colorInteger(66,135,245)` gives `4360181`
And `'#' + colorInteger(66,135,245).toString(16)` gives `"#4287f5"`

To get an integer from the hexadecimal value (without #), you can use `parseInt('4287f5',16)`. You can recover the r,g,b values from that using bit operations, too.

```
function getRGB(hexadecimal_string){
    let intVal = parseInt(hexadecimal_string,16);
    let r = intVal >> 16;
    let g = (intVal >> 8) & 0xff 
    let b = intVal & 0xff 
    return [r,g,b]
}
```

I'm not sure if I understand your intention, but from the answer in another thread ( [Byte order for packed images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296813/byte-order-for-packed-images) ) one single integer like ARGB is represented as [B,G,R,A] in little-endian machines.